# AWS CDK giving unexpected keyword argument 'follow_symlinks' when deploying s3 object

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cdk

I am trying to use AWS CDKversion 1.102.0 (Python) to upload an object to s3 and I am getting an error about unexpected keyword "follow_symlinks"

Code snippet ...
targetBucket = _s3.Bucket.from_bucket_name(self, "ExistingS3Bucket",
'mybucket'
);

```
    uploadObject = _s3deploy.BucketDeployment(self, 'myObject',
        sources=[_s3deploy.Source.asset('mydir/myfile.txt')],
        destination_bucket=targetBucket,
        destination_key_prefix='resources/files'
        )
```

Running 'cdk synth' I am getting the following error

```
File "my_stack.py", line XX,
    sources=[_s3deploy.Source.asset('mydir/myfile.txt')],
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/aws_cdk/aws_s3_deployment/__init__.py", line 1028, in asset
    bundling=bundling,
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'follow_symlinks'
```

Any one see what I am missing ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved.  Global package version of s3_asset was only version 1.75.0